# ProgrammingError at /admin/patients/appointment/ column patients_appointment.date does not exist

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I am facing the above error, even though the "date" column is there in the model.

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
    name=models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=CASCADE)
    doctor=models.ForeignKey(DoctorDetail, on_delete=CASCADE)
    start_time=models.TimeField()
    end_time=models.TimeField()
    date=models.DateField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name.name
```

This was the error I was facing:
[image]

I am using Heroku postgres database. After testing I found out that it is working fine on a local database. Any fixes??

Comment: Did you run makemigrations and migrate ?

Comment: @rahul.m Yes I have

Comment: Is the column added in the database table?

Comment: @Bairavan it is added